# ajax post working locally but not when deployed

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Can anyone see anything i m doing wrong with this as its driving me a bit mad (not sure if it friday brain or baby brain) anyway...

I have a Ajax post which works fine locally but doesnt work when i deploy to another server.

I've put lots of alerts in to make sure I'm getting the parameters that i expect so not quite sure whats missing.

Here is the ajax post:

View:

```
 var theUrl = "/Widgets/TestBin2AutomationResults/" + widgetImpressionId + "/" + retailerProductId + "/" + quantity;
                        alert("widgetImpressionId" + widgetImpressionId);
                        alert("retailerProductId" + retailerProductId);
                        alert("quantity" + quantity);
                        alert(theUrl);
                        $("#imgaddtocart").hide();
                        $("#addMe").unbind('click');
                        $("#delete").unbind('click');

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: theUrl,
                            data: { 'username': username, 'password': password },
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {

                                if (data != null) {
                                    alert("we are inside data");
```

Controller:

```
        [JsonpFilter]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public JsonResult TestBin2AutomationResults(int widgetImpressionId, int retailerProductId, int quantity, string username, string password)
        {


            MessageBox.Show("We are inside TestBin2Automation controller " + widgetImpressionId + "/" + retailerProductId + "/" + quantity + "/" + username + "/" + password);
```

Global.asax

```
 routes.MapRoute("Bin2SubmitTestBin2Automation", "Widgets/TestBin2AutomationResults/{widgetImpressionId}/{retailerProductId}/{quantity}", new { controller = "Widgets", action = "TestBin2AutomationResults", widgetImpressionId = 0, retailerProductId = 0, quantity = 0, username = "", password = "" });
```

I'm not getting into the controller as the MessageBox.Show isn't displaying.

Any help appreciated it d be nice to not have this hanging over my head all weekend!

Many thanks

Comment: Did you check that the correct .js file is being loaded? I've had issues where on deploy (non-debug) the script is looking for the .min.js version of my Ajax stuff but my build did not render (correctly) the .min.js. (My quick fix is to copy contents of .js into .min.js on the live site data.)

Comment: thansk @KristenJukowski i ve checked the source locally and live and they re both link to the same scripts

Comment: @anna try removing the parameters from `theUrl`, then pass it like data json `{'widgetImpressionId': widgetImpressionId, 'retailerProductId':retailerProductId, 'quantity':quantity, 'username': username, 'password': password }`

Comment: @bios thanks for the suggestion - i have tried this but unfortunately works locally but not when i deploy it onto the server

Comment: Is your app being deployed to a virtual or sub directory on your production server?  Running in localhost, your app is at the root of the URL.  If you are in a subdirectory (www.mysite.com/subfolder), your path to your controller action in your first line would most likely be wrong.

Comment: @anna Check your browser console for errors on submit.

Comment: @anna Use a debugger on client-side as well as server-side, and you will know everything in a minute.

Comment: I'm not sure that [MessageBox.Show()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) works even locally. It is windows forms API. It shouldn't work. Check if browser sends a request. Check java-script errors.

Comment: Maybe it's just not displayed either set a breakpoint on the success and error callbacks for the Ajax call. Are you getting an error return?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it was actually that i was trying to access Amazon AWS in the controller but had not put in the Access keys into the config and i thought that it wasn t getting into that controller as it wasn t hitting the first line but when i removed pretty much all the logic out of the controller it entered the controller fine so it wasn t the ajax call at all but rather the logic inside - i just thought as it wasn t getting to the first line it wasn t getting in there which wasn t the case.  So stripping the controller down to be very basic let me know what the actual issue was.

Answer (score 3):

i am also face this issue in my mvc project ....

i am solved this issue by following steps.

1) Put this in your Layout page in script section

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var RootUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")';
</script>
```

2) add the "RootUrl" variable in ajax url. (it's also working your Js File you add "RootUrl" before your ajax url)

```
var theUrl = RootUrl +"Widgets/TestBin2AutomationResults/" + widgetImpressionId + "/" + retailerProductId + "/" + quantity;
```

It's working prefect for me but anyone have other solution then plz post me

Answer (score 0):

Since the ajax post works locally,try and enable CORS on the live web server. Cross-origin domain is the likely reason behind the problem you're having. What are using on your backend? Is it PHP, ASP.NET or Python?

Comment: as long I see, there's no need to enable CORS because the request is under the same domain, the backend is asp.net mvc

Answer (score 0):

your URL is started with "/" it means it will try to resolve URL from root of domain. Please verify your application is deployed in root of domain or under any virtual directory. If it is deployed under virtual directory than you need to change JavaScript code to include virtual directory while making AJAX call.